# Can anyone explain to me this line of code of 140 characters?

Tags: javascript, html

Its extracted from a challenge on twitter where you have to make a game only with the 140 characters of a twitt.

In the snippet dont work correctly but if you save it into an .html extension file it will work.

```html
<body onload=d=Date.now,t=d(s=0)><p style="float:left" onclick="(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3?style.margin=e%300+' 0 0 '+e*7%300:alert(s)">X</p></body>
```

it has a weird syntax...

Comment: It's just javascript, that's been "minified / uglified" so you can't easily read the function names.  Break it down.  Test it in your console / browser.

Comment: And it *does too* work correctly.  It's a time-based function.  Click the X.  Wait a while. Click it again.  (If nothing happens, wait a while longer, click again).

Comment: It's a sort of game.  To see how many times you can click the X within a certain amount of seconds.

Comment: It's not working on my chrome. The margins need units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking it down:

```
<body onload=d=Date.now,t=d(s=0)>
```

This is just simply a body tag with an onload event handler. It's javascript code that will run once the element is loaded.

```
d=Date.now
```

Just saves the function into a `window.d`, which is easier to access through `d`.

```
t=d(s=0)
```

It's the same as doing `t=Date.now(s=0)`. `Date.now` doesn't use any arguments, so it's the same as doing `t=Date.now()`. He's just using the function call arguments to initialize `s` to `0`. So now, he has 3 variables:

```
d=Date.now;
t=Date.now(); //the timestamp when the body loads
s=0;
```

Then there's the `p` element:

```
<p style="float:left" onclick="(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3?style.margin=e%300+' 0 0 '+e*7%300:alert(s)">X</p>
```

Which has an onclick event handler:

```
(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3?style.margin=e%300+' 0 0 '+e*7%300:alert(s)
```

This is just a ternary expression (similar to if/else). Which you can break into 3 parts. The condition, the truth expression, the false expression.

The condition is:

```
(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3
```

`15e3` is `15000`. So you have:

```
(e=d(++s)-t) < 15000
```

The first part:

```
(e=d(++s)-t)
```

Is an assignment expression (which returns the assigned value). Doing `d(++s)` is the same as doing `Date.now(++s)`. Remember that the function doesn't do anything with the arguments, he's just using the arguments in the function call to increase `s` by 1. `Date.now` is returning the timestamp right then (when you click on the `p` element).

It then substracts that timestamp with the previous timestamp (stored in `t`) and stores it in `e`. `e` is now the milliseconds between the click and since the body loaded.

So:

```
(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3
```

Is comparing the amount of miliseconds with 15000. If it's less than 15 seconds, the truth expression runs, if it's more than 15 second the false expression runs.

The truth expression is doing:

```
style.margin=e%300+' 0 0 '+e*7%300
```

It's a very simple way to move around the `p` element around. The boundaries are presumably 300, so `e%300` will return a margin that's less than 300. The other margin is being multiplied by 7 so they are different.

`style.margin` works because event handlers get parsed in a very peculiar way. Basically, you can access any property of the element as if it was in scope.

The false expression:

```
alert(s);
```

Just prints the number of times you have clicked.

It didn't work on my chrome, until I added units:

```html
<body onload=d=Date.now,t=d(s=0)><p style="float:left" onclick="(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3?style.margin=e%300+'px 0 0 '+e*7%300 + 'px':alert(s)">X</p></body>
```

It's a game to see how many times you can click X before 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i think the original function names were:

Basically, it check how much time is elapsed since the page load and adds margin if clicked before 15 seconds. I changed it to 5 seconds and added color red instead of margin.

```html
<body onload="date = Date.now, time = date(clicks = 0)">
  <p onclick="(elapsed = date(++clicks)-time) < 5000 ? this.style.color='red' : alert('Clicks:'+clicks)"> Click me within 5 seconds.
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

onload function:

d is just a shortcut to the Date.now(), every time it's invoked it will produce a different result. the parameter is not related to the function in any way, Date.now() will produce the same result when called with any parameter, so

t=d(s=0)

records the time when the page was loaded, and also sets s (number of clicks) to zero.

onclick function:

this uses the shorthand format

boolean ? true case : false case

, so

(e=d(++s)-t)<15e3 ?

e is the difference between the page load time and the current time. Again the ++s parameter doesn't affect the function, but just increments the number of clicks recorded. If this difference is less than 15e3 ( aka 15000 in decimal miliseconds, or 15 seconds ) , it switches the top margin and left margin of the

element, using the "top right bottom left" margin format. You will notice that the 2 numbers in the middle stay at 0 and only the top and left are changed on click.

The random numbers  for margins ( between 0 and 300 ) are given by taking the time difference and dividing it ( modulus ) by 300 for top margin, and by multiplying times 7 before doing the same math for left margin, so the numbers are not the same and the X doesn't move diagonally only.

Once 15 seconds have elapsed, the next subsequent click alerts the value of s.

Comment: Good catch on `d(s=0)`. Who would think of doing that to save a semi-column though?

Comment: I thought it was done on purpose to confuse ppl, didn't realize he saved 1 char :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you have here is HTML which contains some JS. Uglified scripts use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of the common `if {} else {}` statement. This version of the code might help understanding it:

```
<body onload=d=Date.now,t=d(s=0)>
    <p style="float:left" onclick="clickFunction()">X</p>
</body>

<script>

  var clickFunction = function() {

      if((e = d(++s) - t) < 15e3) {

          style.margin = e % 300 + ' 0 0 ' + e * 7 % 300;

      } else {

          alert(s);

      }

  }

</script>
```